# How to keep the variable from returning to original value each time I use the onClick event

Tags: javascript, html, loops, if-statement, onclick

Hi I have the following HTML and javascript code for an ATM withdrawl machine. The code works but the balance does not decrease (starts at 400$) after each withdrawl from the user.I can't find what is the problem or how to get around this issue. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>ATM</title>
    <style>
        #bank {
            text-align: center;
        }

        button {
            padding-left: 6px;
            padding-right: 6px;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Q2.js">
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <form id="bank">
        <h2> Question 2 </h2>
        <h5>ATM Machine</h5>
        <input type="text" id="cash" placeholder="Enter withdrawal amount" size="25">
        <button type="submit" onclick="validateAmount()" id="button">Submit</button>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Here is the javascript

```
balance = 400.00;


function validateAmount() {
    a = document.getElementById("cash");
    amount = a.value;

    if (isNaN(amount)) {
        alert("Please enter a numeric value");
    } else {

            withdrawlAmount();
    }
}

function withdrawlAmount() {


    if (amount >= balance)
        alert("Insufficent Funds");
    else if (amount % 20 != 0)
        alert("Incorrect withdrawl amount");
    else if (amount < balance) {
        alert("Succeful transaction\nCurrent Balance: " + (balance - amount) + "$");
        balance -= amount;
    } else {
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you get as alert?

Comment: Please declare your variables. Using globals like this is just going to confuse you and result in bad code. Also, amount is a string, not a number.

Answer (score 3):

Your HTML submit button will refresh the page every time you press it, thus re-running your javascript and resetting the balance to 400. To fix this, change the button type from "submit" to "button".

Answer (score 0):

Some things to address:

1. **Prevent the default action.** When capturing a submit event, you're going to want to prevent the default action from occurring using `event.preventDefault()` inside the event listener so that the page doesn't redirect.
2. **Declare your identifiers.** When you don't declare an identifier using `var`, `let`, or `const`, it becomes a global identifier and pollutes the global scope. Dealing with globals and undeclared identifiers *will* result in code that is less readable, and will probably result in confusion for you. I'll leave further explanation of this to the countless other articles on the topic.
3. **Encapsulate your code.** Your code might be the only code running on the page in this specific example, but largely it won't be in real life. Encapsulate your code, and keep it safe from other scripts while keeping other scripts safe from your script.

Above and beyond that, this is how I would go about it:

```js
function ATM(balance, amount) {
  this.receiver = document.createElement('template');
  this.build();
  this.balance = balance || 0;
  this.amount = amount || 0;
}
ATM.prototype = {
  build() {
    this.receiver.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `
      <form id="atm-form">
        <h1>ATM</h1>
        <p><label>Balance: <input id="balance" value="0.00" readonly></label></p>
        <p><label>Amount: <input id="amount" value="0.00"></label></p>
        <p><button type="submit">Withdraw</button></p>
      </form>
    `);

    this.nodes = {
      form: this.receiver.querySelector('#atm-form'),
      balance: this.receiver.querySelector('#balance'),
      amount: this.receiver.querySelector('#amount')
    };

    this.nodes.form.addEventListener('submit', event => {
      event.preventDefault();
      const result = this.withdraw();
      this.receiver.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('withdraw', { detail: { result } }));
    });
    this.nodes.balance.addEventListener('change', event => {
      this.balance = this.nodes.balance.value;
    });
    this.nodes.amount.addEventListener('change', event => {
      this.amount = this.nodes.amount.value;
    });
  },
  attach(node) {
    if(!(node instanceof Node)) return false;
    node.appendChild(this.nodes.form);
    return true;
  },
  validate() {
    const result = { valid: false, error: null };
    if(isNaN(this.amount)) {
      result.error = 'Please enter a numeric value.';
    } else if(this.amount > this.balance) {
      result.error = 'Please enter a value less than the balance.';
    } else if(this.amount <= 0) {
      result.error = 'Please enter a value greater than 0.';
    } else {
      result.valid = true;
    }
    return result;
  },
  withdraw() {
    let result = { success: false, error: null, amount: this.amount, balance: this.balance };
    const { valid, error } = this.validate();
    if(valid) {
      this.balance = this.balance - this.amount;
      result.balance = this.balance;
      result.success = true;
    } else {
      result.error = error;
    }
    return result; 
  },
  addEventListener(type, callback) {
    this.receiver.addEventListener(type, callback);
  },
  removeEventListener(type, callback) {
    this.receiver.removeEventListener(type, callback);
  },
  formatCurrency(value) {
    return Number.parseFloat(value).toFixed(2);
  },
  set amount(value) {
    this.nodes.amount.value = this.formatCurrency(value);
  },
  get amount() {
    return this.formatCurrency(this.nodes.amount.value);
  },
  set balance(value) {
    this.nodes.balance.value = this.formatCurrency(value);
  },
  get balance() {
    return this.formatCurrency(this.nodes.balance.value);
  }
}

const atm = new ATM(400.00);
atm.attach(document.body);
atm.addEventListener('withdraw', ({ detail: { result } }) => {
  console.log('Withdraw event: ', result)
});
```